# Storm Exception : Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken

Tags: apache-storm, topology

Hi I set up storm on a production server. Running `supervisorctl status` gives the following outpug

```
storm_nimbus                     RUNNING    pid 24955, uptime 15:51:16
storm_supervisor                 RUNNING    pid 24953, uptime 15:51:16
storm_ui                         RUNNING    pid 24956, uptime 15:51:16
zookeeper                        RUNNING    pid 24954, uptime 15:51:16
```

The processes are running fine however when i submit my topology I get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read. Shell Process Exception: at backtype.storm.utils.Disruptor
```

I don't know why this happens since my topology work fine when I run locally. How do I trace the cause of this error. I am new to storm so ...

THE ERROR IN DETAIL:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Shell Process Exception:


    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:87)
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:58)
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:62)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4050$fn__4059$fn__4106.invoke(executor.clj:658)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:377)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Shell Process Exception:


    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.execute(ShellBolt.java:139)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4050$tuple_action_fn__4052.invoke(executor.clj:566)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__3976.invoke(executor.clj:345)
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1606.onEvent(disruptor.clj:43)
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:84)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Shell Process Exception:


    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readString(ShellProcess.java:100)
    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readMessage(ShellProcess.java:62)
    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt$1.run(ShellBolt.java:90)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What is your Storm version? and are using Python to create your topology?

Comment: I am using storm version 0.8.2 and python 2.7. And yes I am using python to create my topologies

Answer (score 0):

I checked the storm worker logs (../storm/logs/) and found out that the issue was an error in my spout programming. I was referencing a file that did not exist Issue is resolved now. Thanks anyways